# How do I move files based on a certain character length range?

Tags: regex, linux, mv

I have the following files in a directory:

```
f.txt
fi.txt
fil.txt
file.txt
filen.txt
filena.txt
filenam.txt
filename.txt
filenametoolong.txt
```

I want to move all except the last one. This following regular expression applies to my needs: ^.{1,13}.txt

However, using the regex with with "mv"

```
mv ^.{1,13}\.txt trashdir
```

Results in

```
mv: cannot stat `^.1.txt': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `^.24.txt': No such file or directory
```

I have checked and double checked the regex syntax, and it seems to be valid. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mv` command doesn't support regex. You can use `find` with `-regex` option:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '\./.\{1,13\}' -exec mv {} /trashdir +
```

Comment: Well, that's...funny. Anyway, what is the "+" at the end for? Also, is it alright to remove the prefix "/" before "trashdir", so it won't try to execute in root?

Comment: Yes you can use any relative path in place of `/trashdir` as destination dir. `+` is for termination of your command that comes after `-exec` and is considered more efficient than use of `\;`. Check `man find` for more details.

Comment: I tried your command but got `find: missing argument to '-exec'` I stripped down the find command to just `find . -regex '\./.\{1,13\}'` and it comes up blank.

Comment: Can you try to run: `find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '\./.{1,13}'` command